# Pandas rolling apply to df where filter based on values in current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a datetime column (that I've used as a DatetimeIndex) that has a categorical column, and a numerical column. I'd like to apply a complex function to the numerical column when the categorical column is the same as the current row, in a short (ten-day) window lagging the current row (non-inclusive).

As a contrived example:

```
name = ['steve', 'bob', 'harry', 'jeff'] * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-10-10', end='2018-10-29', freq='D'), 
    data={'value': [x for x in range(20)],
          'name': names
         }
)
```

produces a simple dataframe, to which I'd like to add another column (`result`) that calculates the number of rows * the sum of the values in 'value' (or something - just a formula that there's not a Pandas built-in function for). So for the dataframe above, I'd like the following:

```
            num   name  result
2018-10-10    0  steve     NaN    
2018-10-11    1    bob     NaN
2018-10-12    2  harry     NaN
2018-10-13    3   jeff     NaN
2018-10-14    4  steve       0
2018-10-15    5    bob       1
2018-10-16    6  harry       2
2018-10-17    7   jeff       3
2018-10-18    8  steve       8
2018-10-19    9    bob      12
2018-10-20   10  harry      16
2018-10-21   11   jeff      20
2018-10-22   12  steve      24
2018-10-23   13    bob      28
2018-10-24   14  harry      32
2018-10-25   15   jeff      36
2018-10-26   16  steve      40
2018-10-27   17    bob      44
2018-10-28   18  harry      48
2018-10-29   19   jeff      52
```

I can write my own function for this and use it in `pandas.apply`:

```
def rolling_apply(df, time, window_size=timedelta(days=10)):
    event_time = time
    event_name = df[df.index == time]['names'].iloc[0]

    return df[
        (df['names'] == event_name) & 
        (df.index < event_time) & 
        (df.index >= event_time - window_size)
    ]

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: rolling_apply(df, x.name)['value'].sum() * rolling_apply(df, x.name).count(), axis=1)
```

but performance gets pretty terrible pretty quickly as my data grows. `pandas.rolling.apply` seems sort of appropriate, but I can't quite make it fit what I want to do.

Any suggestions or help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: "I can write my own function for this and use it in pandas.apply" - show the code.

Comment: The logic isn't clear from this, can you please explain a little more?

Comment: Edited to show the code I tried.